# Why is Firebase Authentication using so much storage space?

Tags: java, firebase, google-app-engine, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a web app that uses Firebase Authentication and Firebase Auth Admin to generate a JWT to manage user sessions. From the past day of usage, Firebase Auth currently shows 123 MB of storage and 105 MB of Bandwidth, while I have been the only user to login and test the site. I would like to know why Firebase Auth is storing and sending so much data for only one user.

The storage, bandwidth, and object count usage is heavily generated by the staging.myproject.appspot.com domain compared to the myproject.appspot.com domain. For example, one day from the usage chart shows the non-staging domain using 0 B of bandwidth and the staging domain using 120 MB, with similar concentration for the storage and object count usage charts.

For reference on how I am utilizing Firebase Auth, I have a filter setup for secured pages of the site where I check the JWT as follows:

```
List<FirebaseApp> firebaseApps = FirebaseApp.getApps();
if(firebaseApps != null && firebaseApps.size() == 0)
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp();

final boolean checkRevoked = false;
FirebaseToken decodedToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifySessionCookie(sessionCookie, checkRevoked);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What storage are you talking about here? Is it Firebase Hosting storage and bandwidth in your app that uses Firebase Authentication?

Comment: When I go to the Firebase console and select my project, the top of the page shows a chart with the title storage. When I click on this it takes me to the page showing the Bytes stored, Object count, Bandwidth, and Requests tabs. Do the usage figures on this page count only the resources used by Firebase products or the entire App Engine application?

Comment: Firebase Storage disk space and bandwidth usage has nothing to do with Firebase Authentication. Apparently you're storing 123MB worth of files in Cloud Storage through Firebase. The `files` panel in the Firebase Storage console shows you exactly files are stored in there.

Comment: I have not setup Firebase Storage. When I click on the files tab, it takes me to the storage page and shows the 'Get Started' button, which opens the 'Set up Cloud Storage' modal.

Comment: Interesting. It sounds like you shouldn't have any storage usage in that case. Can you check if anything shows up Cloud Storage for your project in https://console.cloud.google.com/storage/browser/? If not, it might be worth to [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting as this could be a bug in our console (or elsewhere).

Comment: After checking the Cloud Storage console, the only bucket that contains anything is the staging bucket.

Comment: Is that anything significant enough in the staging project to explain the 123MB storage? And is there part of your project reading/writing from the staging storage bucket, which would explain the bandwidth?